# Blank White Screen in Browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access an external .js file. called helloworld.js

I have witten the code in html but when I run the code in a browser
I receive a blank white screen. I'm baffled at this because I have
validated the code and it was successful.

How do I solve this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="helloworld.js">
</script>

</head>


<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For this to work, helloworld.js has to be in the same directory as the html page. Is it? Also, what's the expected outcome?

Comment: You'll probably need to provide your helloworld.js for us to help.

Comment: Check the Events and the Javascript Console panels in your browser's developer tools to se if there is a javascript error somewhere. Also, inspect the JS file to check if it was loaded correctly.

Comment: I have already validated the code for the .html file and it was successful. the .js file simply has a document.write("HelloWorld"); statement,but excludes the <script></script> tag and any comments as stated in the example I am following from at the following website:http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/basicjavascript.html

Comment: @worldofjr - The .html and .js file are in the same directory. I'mbaffled as to why it does not work as I am following an example online. Can you help out?

Comment: @RobertoLinares - I have checked the javascript console using firebug there are no errors recorded.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> - Syntax Error -- Why is the Inspect Element specify an error in my doctype declaration?

Comment: @user3018137 - which browser (and version of it) are you using?